# PL/SQL Fill object with data from tables

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, constructor, object-type

I have custom object created in pl/sql. What I want to do is to create object passing `id` from table and fill object attributes with data from one row (speciefied by this `id`). How to do this? I'm working in oracle 10g.

My type looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE userType AS OBJECT(
    id number,
    name varchar2(100),
    nickname varchar2(100),
    email varchar2(100),
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION userType(userId number) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);
```

And `type body` declaration:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY userType AS
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION userType(userId number) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
    AS
    BEGIN
        self.id := userId;
        self.name := ???;    --<- need help there  
        self.nickname := ??? --(something like select name from userType where id = userId)                   
        (and so on)
        RETURN;
    END;
END;
```

Table columns have the same name as `userType` attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be able to do the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY userType AS
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION userType(userId number) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
    AS
    BEGIN
        self.id := userId;
        SELECT name, nickname INTO self.name, self.nickname FROM user_table WHERE id = userId;                   
        RETURN;
    END;
END;
```

Although I'm not sure on whether this is the correct or best way.

Comment: @Exhausted What do you mean by "any answer"? It worked for fine for me when I tested it (although I am using 11g)

Comment: this is exactly what I'm lookin for, thank you! :) It works fine and is very simple :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to do this

```
SQL> desc employ
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ---------------------------

 ID                                                 NUMBER
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(50)


SQL> select * from employ
  2  ;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 Exhaust
         2 Object
         3 Fill



SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace type usertype as object
  2  (
  3  id number,
  4  name varchar2(50),
  5  constructor function usertype(userId number) return self as result
  6* );
SQL> /

Type created.


SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace type body usertype as
  2  constructor function usertype(userid number) return self as result
  3  as
  4  outvar employ.name%type;
  5  begin
  6  self.id := userid;
  7  select name into outvar from employ where id = userid;
  8  self.name := outvar;
  9  return;
 10  end;
 11* end;
SQL> /

Type body created.



SQL> declare
  2  v_usertype usertype;
  3  begin
  4  v_usertype := usertype(1);
  5  dbms_output.put_line(v_usertype.name);
  6  end;
  7  /
Exhaust

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```